# Upgrade to 19.10 broke my DEL key

Tags: upgrade, keyboard

Since the upgrade to Ubuntu 19.10, when I press the DEL key in a text input or terminal it doesn't delete the next character. Instead it will insert the Unicode DEL character U+007F.